# Access sub-domain with www

Tags: dns, subdomain, no-www

I successfully have `sub.example.com` pointing to an IP address using an A record.

However, `www.sub.example.com` does not resolve.

How do I fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is being downvoted. It took me forever to find the solution and I'm still not 100% sure that it's correct. Maybe instead of downvoting, you could actually answer the question.

Comment: I would guess that down voters consider this too easy of a question with too obvious of an answer.   I'm glad you were able to figure out a solution.   Those of us that have been creating sites for a while know how to add the DNS records but we may not remember how confusing it was when we first started.

Answer (score 2):

Answer my own question here. It looks like you need to create a CNAME record with the host of "www.sub" and the value of "sub.example.com"

Comment: Each record is independent, so you need to do to `www.sub.example.com` exactly what you did to `sub.example.com` to make it resolve.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek A CNAME as above will work fine (albeit causing an extra lookup.  There is no requirement for an A record here as would be required for sub.example.com - although an A record would work as well - arguably better as there is 1 less lookup involved)

Comment: @davidgo I never said there is a requirement for any type of record. I just said that you need to provision the second name as you did provision the first one, as each name is independent. And each name can be provisioned differently (A vs AAAA vs CNAME vs DNAME vs BNAME vs SRV vs HTTPS records, etc.)

Comment: @patrickmevzek What threw me was your statement that each name is independent. This is not true case with CNAMES - https://kb.isc.org/v1/docs/en/aa-01640 (or DNAMES) is a good read here.  Also, a while you can't mix/have both CNAMES  and other record types for a subdomain you can - have A and AAAA records and SRV records for the same source/subdomain. AFAIK there is no such thing as a BNAME, and an HTTPS records are not an approved part of a standard.

Comment: @davidgo Independent in the sense provisioning one does not make the other suddenly resolve. As I think the OP thought that by configuring `sub.example.com` then `www.sub.example.com` which is below would be configured automatically. It doesn't because both names are independent to each other provisioning wise even if one "under" the other (and yes, no need to talk about wildcards). I think you are completely missing the point of my comment. Even with a CNAME: if you have `sub.example.com` a CNAME, that has no impact on `www.sub.example.com` that needs to be provisioned (again, A, or CNAME.)

Comment: `BNAME` exists as proposal. And `HTTPS` will be soon a standard (and is already used in the wild, see Apple and CloudFlare announcements). I am really not sure what you are trying to argue about there. You are missing the whole global point and targeting minor details, which you get wrong anyway.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I've been doing some Googling, and my Google-Fu is weak.  Can you point me to the RFC for BNAME and the messages - I'm genuinely interested in the topic.   Do you know if any major DNS servers/resolvers support these record types?  (Also, while the first response to mine is reasonable, the last line of your second comment is, in my opinion out of line - the reason for my commenting is that CNAMES are wildly misunderstood and its important to me people don't get the wrong idea of how they work)  ...

Comment: Also. for sake of completeness on CNAMES - and talking to the heart of the matter if www.example.com exists, and sub.example.com is a CNAME to example.com, www.sub.example.com will resolve the same way www.example.com will, even if www.sub.example.com does not appear in the zone file.

Comment: Based on my experience, for people new to DNS,it is better not to speak too much about "CNAME" otherwise they do too many mistakes with it. As explained above my comment was targeting one misconception that I think was described in the question. As for BNAME you can find a specification at https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-yao-dnsext-bname-06 ;and your latest example it is not clear (you seem to mix `www.` and apex at the beginning) and even maybe wrong.If `sub.example.com CNAME whatever.example` then `other.sub.example.com` will not resolve if not configured. You mix things with wildcards...